# How to Handle Enter Key Using TextWatcher on Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, keylistener, textwatcher

I am working on Android. Previously i used `onKeyListener` to handle specific action on key event.

However, this way seems not to solve my problem since almost all key would get disable once i have implemented that listener to my `EditText`. After reading some topics in SO, i know that i should use TextWatcher instead, but i'm still wondering how to handle `ENTER` key event inside because parameters provided there are only `CharSequence`, `Editable`, etc. I didn't find any `keyCode` parameters.

Comment: `However, this way seems not to solve my problem since almost all key would get disable once i have implemented that listener to my EditText.`..seams like your code is not correct. It should work. with `text watcher` you can not get `Enter event`

Comment: why was my question being down voted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this

```
protected View.OnKeyListener onEnter = new View.OnKeyListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
            //here do what you want
        }
        return false; // very important
    }
};
```

Comment: According to doc: _Called when a hardware key is dispatched to a view._

Comment: As Divers said, KeyListener actually listens to hardware keys (volume, home, etc.).

Answer (score 18):

try this

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    if (s.length()>0 && s.subSequence(s.length()-1, s.length()).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("\n")) {
        //enter pressed
    }
}
```

Comment: @user2348959 that method isn't fit for the purpose.  If you move up a line with back space this also gets called.

Comment: @user2348959 it works if new line appears at the end of the string.. but it is not working new line appears in between the string

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the better solution, because you can press 'Enter' in any place of your EditText field and not only at the end of line.

```
    edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int st, int ct,
                                      int af) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.length() < 1 || start >= s.length() || start < 0)
                return;

            // If it was Enter
            if (s.subSequence(start, start + 1).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("\n")) {

                // Change text to show without '\n'
                String s_text = start > 0 ? s.subSequence(0, start).toString() : "";
                s_text += start < s.length() ? s.subSequence(start + 1, s.length()).toString() : "";
                edittext.setText(s_text);

                // Move cursor to the end of the line
                edittext.setSelection(s_text.length());
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: "It is an error to attempt to make changes to s from this callback." https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html#onTextChanged(java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20int)